# angularjs datetime-local setting now()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

In template:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submitQuery()">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="latestInput">ending time</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="latestInput" name="latestInput" 
     ng-model="latest" placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" required />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
var now = new Date();
$scope.latest = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());
```

I'd like to have the latestInput set up to display time when user launched the page, it works in the [`documentation example`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5BdateTimeLocal%5D) but not in my code, nor in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d91CZS88OsmJMt6oyo9p?p=preview

what's wrong with this?

Note: 
I had angular telling me

> Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

when I tried to use `new Date(2014, 29, 7, 10, 38);` 
this is why I'm using `now`

Comment: Isn't `datetime-local` dropped? [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22654498/1763929)

Comment: but why angular plunker in the reference works? http://plnkr.co/edit/19GPhqcju7C1X3pKG6wL?p=preview

Comment: I don't think it works without a `<form>` tag. Angular reference also has a `<form>` tag

Comment: Updated code above and plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input type `datetime-local` is only supported from AngularJS 1.3.0.beta1 onwards (as well `date`, `time`, `month` and `week`):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta1-retractable-eyebrow-2014-03-07

Answer (score 2):

In your demo, you are using angular version `1.2.20` which is a stable release that does not have a support for `datetime-local`.

Updating the plunkr works for me. http://plnkr.co/edit/t3OqrDCQOsdm5AqLBSRY?p=preview

Always check the angular version (top left corner) the documentation is using:
[image]